# Strange ' Data truncation: Out of range value' error for Decimal column

Tags: mysql

I have a column `foo` in a mysql table, which is of the type `DECIMAL (10,10)`.

If I try to insert a record in it with the value of `foo` as 100.0, that produces the error ' Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'foo' at row 1`

What am I doing wrong - doesn't `10,10` means upto 10 digits both before and after the decimal point, which should allow for this number?

Comment: Decimal 10,10= 10 positions max with 10 decimals present. Try 10,2 instead or 20,10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the first value means the total digits, and the second means the digits after the comma,

so,

```
20,10 = 20 Digits and 10 after comma => 10, before and ten after
```

A packed "exact" fixed-point number. M is the total number of digits (the precision) and D is the number of digits after the decimal point (the scale). The decimal point and (for negative numbers) the "-" sign are not counted in M. If D is 0, values have no decimal point or fractional part and on INSERT the value will be rounded to the nearest DECIMAL. The maximum number of digits (M) for DECIMAL is 65. The maximum number of supported decimals (D) is 30. If D is omitted, the default is 0. If M is omitted, the default is 10.

Comment: Thanks For valuable Info

Answer (score 1):

If you want 10 digit and 10 decimal the you need

```
DECIMAL (20,10)
```

The first value define the total number of digit .. the secondo the max digit after the decimal point

Comment: Shouldn't 10,10 still mean 100.0 should be accepted?

Comment: Even with 30,30 100.0 is not being accepted. May be something else is going on here

Comment: 30,30   then 30,30 mean only 30 digit after decimal point  .. no integer part , 100,0 mean no decimal part..so you try 0.00000000--> 30 don't work .. because you have an integer (0.) value .. if you try 1111111->100.1 don't work you have a decimal digit ..